# Perfmon Disk Operations are Lower Than Process IO Operations

Tags: windows, perfmon

I'm trying to compare io operations of some process against total disk operations using Windows Performance Monitor.

I used the following counters:

- `\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Reads/sec`, and
- `\Process(<process_name>)\IO Read Operations/sec`

After summing the results from each counter, I noticed that the process is doing 3x more IO Read Operation than Disk Reads operations. I also tried to do the compare IO reads of a dummy process that only read files (without any other operations) and the total disk reads operations, and once again, the number of process read operations was higher than the total disk read operations.

Sometimes, also the sum of results from `\Process(<process_name>)\IO Read Bytes/sec` is higher than the sum of results from `\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Read Bytes/sec`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the system file cache might be the cause of these results.

When the process reads a file it does not necessarily read it from the disk. If this file has been read by any processes before it could stay in the system file cache for a long time (especially if the host has a lot of free memory). So when another process reads this file again, it will read it from memory and that's why `\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Reads/sec` counter will not increment.

You can read more about the system file cache in Windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/subsystem/cache-memory-management/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Not all IO goes to disk. Try a simple netweork demon, that produces no Disk IO at all.

Next: An IO for a process doesn't equal an IO for the system. Consider a simple dummy application, that opens a file (located on a disk with 512B/sector) and then reads one byte every second. The process will see one disk IO per second, the system will see only one every 512 seconds. This stems from the fact, that the system can read only in blocksize chunks, but the application in arbitrary quanta.

Additionally: Even Windows does some basic elevator work: Disk requests are not fulfilled strictly as they are queued, but they are triaged, priorized and possibly merged. The latter will result in a reduction of IOs. Again consider a dummy program, that does nothing else than overwrite the same byte in a file with a different value over and over again. The process will see IO operations at a very high rate, but not every single write will actually git the Disk (if not explicitly requested by the process). A mssive number of IOs will just be merged into a single one at writeback time.